# Django FloatField field is required on admin

Tags: python, django

I've got a field for additional_salary

```
additional_salary = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Issue is on the django admin the field keeps throwing an error if I don't fill anything as `field is required` I thought maybe null would fix it.
I've done a migration, restarted gunicorn but the error persisted.

Decided I would remove the field for now as I debugged. Removed it, did the migration and restarted gunicorn again but the field even though not visible on the form still throws an error.

Not sure why but I'm starting to think django 2.0 might have lazy loaded the javascript, using nginx with it.

[image]

**UPDATE**
Just to get it working I've tried having it using `default=0` but it kept throwing the same error. Even when I got more curious and set it to 1 and it raised the same error I'm now convinced Django 2.0 has an actual bug.

I even switched it to a DecimalField

`additional_salary = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)`

still got the same error with nothing in the field and even a value of 0.02

[image]

Comment: required is not a valid field option in django 2.0

Answer (score 0):

in admin panel try the
 `exclude = ['additional_salary`] in your admin model
( I just assume things, because i cant see your models and admin.py)
I imagine it is something like

```
class PoliticianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   exclude = ('additional_salary', )
```

or could be like this

```
class PoliticianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['your', 'fields', 'to', 'display']
```

Comment: funny enough exclude doesn't solve the problem. BTW I've removed the field and excluding a field that doesn't exist should throw an error and even the fact when filling the form the field is hidden only throwing an error even without a field to fill in the data.

Comment: May be you could try using models.DecimalField ? I mean that error is weird.   also setting it up w/ blank and null with True.